# How to seralize a MethodField with more than one object in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to serialize a method that checks if the author of a story is the currently logged in user, if so returns true, if not false. However, the [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) of Django state that the Serliazer method requires only one argument besides self. So how can I access the user model in addition to the story (object)?

I was thinking about something like that:

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    story_owner_permission = serializers.SerializerMethodField('check_story_owner_permission')

    class Meta:
        model = Story 
        fields =  ['story_owner_permission']

    def check_story_owner_permission(self, story, request):
        story_author = story.author.id
        current_user = request.user.id
        if (story_author == current_user):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

But it doesn't work. `check_story_owner_permission() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `context` in serializer, by default if you call your serializer from view, view have filled it automatically ([see](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) `get_serializer_context`):

```
class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    story_owner_permission = serializers.SerializerMethodField('check_story_owner_permission')

    class Meta:
        model = Story 
        fields =  ['story_owner_permission']

    def check_story_owner_permission(self, obj):
        return obj.author.id == self.context["request"].user.id
```